# Perl is not deleting a scalar variable. How can I make it not initialize a deleted variable's contents to zero?

Tags: perl

I have a simple script to accept standard input. I request that the variable will be a number. But obviously the standard input could take a string like "Hello World". I attempt to delete the variable by making it undefined with "undef", but instead the undefined function makes my variable zero. I then do some mathematics on it to see if the undefined function is actually making my scalar value zero or if it is removing the variable from memory because the natural logarithm of zero is undefined.

I think that it's very important to be able to completely delete a temporary variable's contents from a script after you've done important calculations with it like managing your budget. But Perl seems to disagree. Is there anyway to make a removed variable not be initialized to zero?

Here is a Perl 5 script to test that hypothesis:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# deletion_attempt.pl
use warnings; 

print "Give me a positive number greater than zero\n";
chomp($x = <STDIN>);

$this_log = log($x);
print "The natural logarithm of $x is $this_log";

undef $x; # I'm trying to delete $x. But Perl is initializing $x to zero. 

$new_log = log($x);
print "The natural logarithm of the deleted variable is $new_log";

print "$x";
```

If I provide 10 from the standard input I get this result to standard output.

```
Give me a positive number greater than zero
10
Use of uninitialized value $x in log at deletion_attempt.pl line 13, <STDIN> line 1.
Can't take log of 0 at deletion_attempt.pl line 13, <STDIN> line 1.
The natural logarithm of 10 is 2.30258509299405
```

If I comment out the lines where I calculate the natural logarithm of the undefined scalar value $x, I'm told that the value is undefined, but not that it's zero.

```
Give me a positive number greater than zero
10
Use of uninitialized value $x in string at deletion_attempt.pl line 16, <STDIN> line 1.
The natural logarithm of 10 is 2.30258509299405
```

So Perl is not telling me the truth. It is making an assignment of zero to a variable that I am trying to delete by making it undefined. It is making an assignment instead of deleting the variable or its contents from Perl memory.

Another language like R is smart enough to delete a variable of x, and not set it to zero so you can do mathematics on it. So this realization is making me not very optimistic about Perl programming.

```
> x = 10
> log(x)
[1] 2.302585
> rm(x)
> x
Error: object 'x' not found
> log(x)
Error: object 'x' not found
```

So my question is this: Is there any way to completely delete a variables contents from Perl memory without unintentionally initializing it to zero?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`. This avoids so many problems, and it specifically addresses your question because, among other things, this will prevent you from implicitly creating global variables. You will have to declare your variables with `my`, and where you declare them will affect where they can be seen and used.

For example, take the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all ); 

{    
   print "Give me a positive number greater than zero: ";
   chomp(my $x = <STDIN>);

   my $this_log = log($x);
   print "The natural logarithm of $x is $this_log\n";
}

{
   #print "Give me a positive number greater than zero: ";
   #chomp(my $x = <STDIN>);

   my $new_log = log($x);
   print "The natural logarithm of $x is $new_log\n";
}
```

Trying to run the above fails with the following compile-time error:

```
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $x"?) at a.pl line 17.
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $x"?) at a.pl line 18.
Execution of a.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The program died because you tried to use a variable that doesn't exist, proving that `$x` is no longer in scope.

Comment: I don't get it. The way you formatted my code doesn't accept standard input, and it does not tell me the natural logarithm of x = 10 before it brings it out of scope. What am I missing?

Comment: Perl (and virtually every other language) is much better at this than R. It detects your error at compile-time instead of running half your program before finding your error. You need to fix the error (say by uncommenting the two commented lines) before you can run the program.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's still initializing the variable to zero. I don't see how that's a good thing.

Comment: What are you talking about? The program doesn't even run because the variable doesn't exist, so how can the program that can't run initialize a non-existent variable to zero (or any other value)?

Comment: Also, `undef $x;` (a poor way of saying `$x = undef;`) doesn't "initialize to zero". It sets the value to undef.

Comment: Then how come in my original script without your block separation, if I add "use strict" and "my" variable declarations, it still casts the error message: "Can't take log of 0 at ..." ? It is setting the variable to zero.

Comment: No, to undef. But then you used undef as a number and undef is not a number, so Perl gave you an error (`Use of uninitialized value in log`), and numified undef to zero. "Uninitialized" is a misnomer; it really means "undefined". You would have gotten a similar result with `log("abc")`: `Argument "abc" isn't numeric in log` + `Can't take log of 0`

Answer (score 3):

Perl is telling you about this problem. You get the warning:

> Use of uninitialized value $x in log

But warnings are only warnings. Perl will carry on and try to do the right thing. When it comes to uninitialised values, Perl treats them as empty strings or the number zero depending on the context in which you use them.

If you don't want Perl to do that, then upgrade the warning to a fatal error:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'uninitialized';
```

Then, if you try to access an uninitialised value, you will still see the same warning message, but your program will also die at that point.

**Update:** I should point out that while this solves your current problem, I agree 100% with ikegami, that it's solving a problem that you really shouldn't have. "Deleting a variable" as you describe it (actually, just setting its value to "undef") is not the best approach here. You should be thinking more carefully about the scope of your variables.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I wanted!